# React Native AdMob Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.View.propTypes.style')

Tags: react-native

I tried using react-native-admob package for displaying ads and I followed the instructions in here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob

After setting it up, I'm getting an error:

[image]

Comment: react native is not helping this is sad

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1**. Add below line at top in node-modules/react-native-admob/RNAdmobBanner.js and RNPublisherBanner.js

import PropTypes from "prop-types";

**Step-2**. Delete these line from both file(May be line no is 48 and 50 respective)

style: View.propTypes.style

note: style property of AdmobBanner is not working at all so you can delete this because this is creating issue.

**Step-3**. Change this words in both file

React.PropTypes ===> to ===> PropTypes

old Content=>

```js
bannerSize: React.PropTypes.string,
adUnitID: React.PropTypes.string,
testDeviceID: React.PropTypes.string,
adViewDidReceiveAd: React.PropTypes.func,
didFailToReceiveAdWithError: React.PropTypes.func,
adViewWillPresentScreen: React.PropTypes.func,
adViewWillDismissScreen: React.PropTypes.func,
adViewDidDismissScreen: React.PropTypes.func,
adViewWillLeaveApplication: React.PropTypes.func,
admobDispatchAppEvent: React.PropTypes.func,
```

new content should be like this=>

```js
bannerSize: PropTypes.string,
adUnitID: PropTypes.string,
testDeviceID: PropTypes.string,
adViewDidReceiveAd: PropTypes.func,
didFailToReceiveAdWithError: PropTypes.func,
adViewWillPresentScreen: PropTypes.func,
adViewWillDismissScreen: PropTypes.func,
adViewDidDismissScreen: PropTypes.func,
adViewWillLeaveApplication: PropTypes.func,
admobDispatchAppEvent: PropTypes.func,
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16542#issuecomment-415751870

**OR**

`react-native unlink react-native-admob`

`npm uninstall react-native-admob`

`npm install -save react-native-admob@next`

Docs: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob

Reference: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/391#issuecomment-451253909

For, `react-native-admob@next`, use `adSize` property instead of `bannerSize`

Answer (score 0):

remove style props from AdMobBanner , then check

Comment: I actually added it cause it also throws the error when there's no style

Comment: @VinceGonzales any luck after that

Answer (score 0):

Install the beta version of this plugin. This problem sorts out in this version. the package.json will look like this.

```
"react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
```

Or run this command

```
npm i react-native-admob@2.0.0-beta.6
```